# Why doesn't extracting one second from a video at least result in a multiple of the frame time?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

Trying to get a better understanding on why I'm unable to extract a segment from a movie clip with exact timing, even if I account for clip's frame rate.

For example, if I run the following command on a 29.97 fps video clip in an attempt to extract 1 second of video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -ss 0 -t 1 -c:v huffyuv -an output.avi
```

the duration results in 1.001 seconds.

Now this would make more sense to me if the result was actually a multiple of 0.02997 seconds `(29.97 fps / 1000 ms)` but doing the math to check the multiples `(0.02997, 0.05994, ..., 0.98901, 1.01898, 1.04895)`, I see that the closest multiple is actually be 1.01898 or 1.04895

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact framerate isn't `29.97`, it's `30000/1001`. So each frame has duration of `1001/30000`s, so  30 frames at that rate take up `1001*30/30000` = `1.001` seconds.